# Error in all$import[which(all$import < 1000) - (96 * 7)] : only 0's may be mixed with negative subscripts

Tags: r, time-series

> Hi i am preparing data for forecasting but getting error while preprocessing

```
library(lubridate)
library(ggplot2)
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)
library(dummies)
library(keras)
library(Metrics)
modelversion <- 'base'
all <- read.csv("Data.csv")[,c(1,4,2,3)]
all$Date <- all$tstamp
all$Date <- date(all$Date)
all$Block <- all$blockno
all$import <- all$X.1
all <- all[-c(2:4)]
all$Date[which(all$Block == 96)] <- as.character(ymd(all$Date[which(all$Block == 96)]) - 1)
all$Date <-  ymd(all$Date)
all$Day <- as.factor(as.character(wday(all$Date, label = TRUE)))
all$Block <- as.factor(all$Block)
holidays <- read.csv("Holidays.csv", stringsAsFactors = F)
# holidays <- as.data.frame(t(holidays))
holidays$Date <- dmy(holidays$Date)
is.recursive(holidays)

for(i in 1:nrow(all)){
 all$PublicHoliday[i] <- ifelse(all$Date[i] %in% holidays$Date,1,0)}
all$import[which(all$import < 1000)] <- all$import[which(all$import < 1000) -(96*7)]
```

here after running the above line i get error

`Error in all$import[which(all$import < 1000) - (96 * 7)] : only 0's may be mixed with negative subscripts`

Head of the data is.

| X | Date | Block | import | Day | PublicHoliday |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-04-01 | 1 | 1.44315 | Thu | 0 |
| 2 | 2021-04-01 | 2 | 1.27960 | Thu | 0 |
| 3 | 2021-04-01 | 3 | 1.36600 | Thu | 0 |
| 4 | 2021-04-01 | 4 | 1.41680 | Thu | 0 |
| 5 | 2021-04-01 | 5 | 1.23680 | Thu | 0 |
| 6 | 2021-04-01 | 6 | 1.37030 | Thu | 0 |
| 7 | 2021-04-01 | 7 | 1.37450 | Thu | 0 |
| 8 | 2021-04-01 | 8 | 1.23440 | Thu | 0 |
| 9 | 2021-04-01 | 9 | 1.33100 | Thu | 0 |
| 10 | 2021-04-01 | 10 | 1.37640 | Thu | 0 |

I am really confused here any help will be really appreciated.

> > please find data previous data and its output and current data for which output is giving error.
> > Previous data for which output is correct (not giving any error.).

| X | Date | Block | import | Day | PublicHoliday |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2015-05-01 | 1 | 8456 | Fri | 0 |
| 2 | 2 2015-05-01 | 2 | 8340 | Fri | 0 |
| 3 | 2015-05-01 | 3 | 8560 | Fri | 0 |
| 4 | 2015-05-01 | 4 | 8404 | Fri | 0 |
| 5 | 2015-05-01 | 5 | 8320 | Fri | 0 |
| 6 | 2015-05-01 | 6 | 8236 | Fri | 0 |
| 7 | 2015-05-01 | 7 | 8192 | Fri | 0 |
| 8 | 2015-05-01 | 8 | 8092 | Fri | 0 |
| 9 | 2015-05-01 | 9 | 7968 | Fri | 0 |
| 10 | 2015-05-01 | 10 | 7976 | Fri | 0 |

> The data on which the action is performed is :

| import |
| --- |
| 992 |
| 684 |
| 0 |
| 0 |
| 132 |
| 932 |
| 0 |
| 0 |
| 0 |
| 0 |
| 0 |
| 0 |

> Now note that here most of the values are 0. and the output after the implementation of code

```
 all$import[which(all$import < 1000) -(96*7)]
```

| output |
| --- |
| 5744 |
| 6244 |
| 6040 |
| 6176 |
| 6236 |
| 6088 |
| 7504 |
| 6324 |
| 6900 |
| 7164 |
| 7856 |
| 8136 |
| 8204 |
| 8268 |
| 8684 |
| 8852 |
| 8812 |
| 8848 |
| 8924 |
| 8980 |

> The data for which output is error

| X | Date | Block | import | Day | PublicHoliday |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-04-01 | 1 | 1.44315 | Thu | 0 |
| 2 | 2021-04-01 | 2 | 1.27960 | Thu | 0 |
| 3 | 2021-04-01 | 3 | 1.36600 | Thu | 0 |
| 4 | 2021-04-01 | 4 | 1.41680 | Thu | 0 |
| 5 | 2021-04-01 | 5 | 1.23680 | Thu | 0 |
| 6 | 2021-04-01 | 6 | 1.37030 | Thu | 0 |
| 7 | 2021-04-01 | 7 | 1.37450 | Thu | 0 |
| 8 | 2021-04-01 | 8 | 1.23440 | Thu | 0 |
| 9 | 2021-04-01 | 9 | 1.33100 | Thu | 0 |
| 10 | 2021-04-01 | 10 | 1.37640 | Thu | 0 |

> The data on which the action is performed is :

| output |
| --- |
| 1.44315 |
| 1.27960 |
| 1.36600 |
| 1.41680 |
| 1.23680 |
| 1.37030 |
| 1.37450 |
| 0.00000 |
| 1.23440 |
| 0.00000 |
| 1.33100 |
| 0.00000 |
| 0.00000 |
| 0.00000 |
| 1.37640 |

> which gives error after implementing `all$import[which(all$import < 1000) -(96*7)]`

`Error in all$import[which(all$import < 1000) - (96 * 7)] :  only 0's may be mixed with negative subscripts`

Answer (score 0):

Well i got the answer, its that for dataset for which the output is not showing any error, has all indexes greater than 1000 so i am not getting any error but for the dataset that gives the error indexes were negative after the operation.

I am bit confused why this type of method is used but its old code so still trying to understand the logic behind the used preprocessing method.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).